# keep first row in jtable selected as default

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

I had tried the above code, but when I use this code I cannot retrieve the values using the below code:

```
int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
finalOID=(String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
System.out.println("first oid:"+finalOID);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have look at method for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

```
table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
```

depends of [Selection Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

method must be invoked on `Event Dispatch Thread`, more in the Oracle tutorial [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)